# jQuery(window).resize function trigger only once not every single pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code below to execute my jQuery command once the window is resized above or below 771px. How would I tell the browser to only execute the code once when it breaks above 771px and then again when it goes back below.

```
  jQuery(window).resize(function(){

        if (jQuery(window).width() >= 771){   
            console.log(">"); 

        }  

        if (jQuery(window).width() < 771){    
            console.log("<");    
        } 

   });
```

With this code It is console logging "<" once for every single pixel the browser window changes, so a bunch of times, I would like only once when it goes above and once when it goes back below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser won't do that for you. You'll have to keep the resize event handler, and keep the previous width in a variable. Then compare the current with with the previous one.

Something like this:

```
var previousWidth = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    var currentWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var threshold = 771;

    if (previousWidth < threshold && currentWidth >= threshold)
        console.log(">");

    if (previousWidth >= threshold && currentWidth < threshold)
        console.log("<");

    previousWidth = currentWidth;
});
```